# PC won't power on due to graphics card loop

Tags: boot, power-supply, fan

One day when I decided to turn on my PC, something strange happened. All the fans were running, but I had a blank screen. I then heard my graphics card's (ATi 5770) fan go in to a loop, turning on for a second and turning off for a couple more. It would do that for a couple of minutes, until it decided to get much louder and my PC started to boot normally.

I thought nothing of it at first, but then it started happening much more regularly, and it would take longer to power on each time. Today, the same thing happened. When my PC finally booted, it BSOD'd after a couple minutes of usage.

I opened my PC and checked all the connections. I cleaned out all the dust but I'm still having the same problem. Is this more likely to be a PSU or graphics card issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a though one, I've had something alike, it was a defective graphics card. The best way to test it and easiest, is to go to friend and plug the card in his machine and see if it works. Borrow his card and put it in your machine to test the PSU.

It's probably your gpu though.

Comment: I just tried the GPU in another machine and it works perfectly. Could this be caused by the PSU?

Comment: Could be the PSU, ... or the motherboard I'm affraid.

Comment: Took a stab and bought another PSU. That fixed it!